# If criteria not met redirect to different Razor Page from public async Task OnGetAsync()

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I am new to the "async" and "task" stuff.
I can't seem to get working a simple if{} else{} inside the OnGetAsync().

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoggedStatus") != null)
    {
        //KEEP GOING
    Accounts = await _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
    RedirectToPage("./Index");
    } 
}
```

The error I get is from the Accounts page, which I am trying to avoid even going near by using the "RedirectToPage("./Index")" which is my Home page.
I tried putting "return" word in front of RedirectToPage but it turns red when I do that. Also, if first condition is met (there is a value in the Session object) the Accounts pages shows up with no errors. So, I'm pretty sure the problem is in my attempt to redirect in the "else" statment.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
OESAC.Pages.Accounts.Pages_Accounts_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
        @foreach (var item in Model.Accounts)
```

The error above is in Accounts right where it loops thru and displays rows.
I'm not sure why it even gets to the Accounts.chstml.

Comment: Which page is that? Have you tried putting a breakpoint there and see where the request is coming from? Have you tried your web browser developer tools to see what requests are going on? This doesn't seem to be related to async or task.

Comment: Ok, the accounts page is a page named Index in a folder called "Accounts". The "accounts" page uses the Account Model. And the error is happening in the Index page inside the Accounts folder. I am trying to redirect it one level above to the Home Index file. The reason I think (for me at least) it is an "await" and "async" problem is because if it was an ActionResult with no asyncronous syntax, I could probably hardwire it to work. But I am at a loss how to get the data back and send it using current OnGetAsync() much less turn the code into an Action Result.

Comment: You are sure because probably? Have you tried `RedirectToPage("../Index");`?

Comment: Thanks Paulo. No, that path doesn't work either. This line is what triggers the error,  public IList<OESAC.Models.Accounts> Accounts { get;set; }. I will be away from the computer for 2 days but I hope to continue this troubleshooting when I get back thank you very much.

Comment: Does the page you are redirecting do expect parameters in the URL? Like /Index/id ?

Comment: Hi Brad. No it doesn't it just shows all accounts.

Comment: I'm going to speculate that `Model.Accounts` is `null`.

Comment: Paulo, if I take off the expression tree and just go with the await to the page it works. I wish I was near a computer right now.

Comment: Back at a computer: Paulo, I agree the Model.Accounts is null but why is it even using the Accounts model because it is supposed to be going to the Home page in the folder above? I added an extra "dot" to the RedirectToPage("./Index"); like you said, and that works alone, but not with the If Else statement.

Comment: I left the Else statement, but commented out the RedirectToPage("../Index") and I put a break point inside the Else (empty else), and it still gave me the null model, from the Accounts.cshtml loop. (same error). For some reason it keeps going over to the Accounts.cshtml no matter what.

Comment: If I could just turn the whole "OnGetAsync()" to a plain old "OnGet()" since there are only several rows in the Accounts table, I would be happy. But I have no idea how to turn this: "  Accounts = await _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();" into a regular Razor Page return. The current code without the branching returns the Accounts page with the rows. But I have no idea how to get rid of the whole "async/task" syntax and just return the rows.

Comment: And. . . .not to blather on adnaseum, I have figured a workaround hack, which protects the accounts. I would much rather just redirect to home page (../Index) like nothing happened. 

Here is what I did for the Else statment:
                Accounts = await _context.Accounts.Where(a => a.Id == 10000).ToListAsync();
Someday there might be a 10,000th Account Id, but highly unlikely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Task<IActionResult>` in `public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()`, combined with a `return` statement.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoggedStatus") != null)
    {
        //KEEP GOING
        Accounts = await _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();

        return Page();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    } 
}
```

---

Microsoft's docs has some good read on this here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

---

Based on a comment, you can run this w/o async.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoggedStatus") != null)
    {
        //KEEP GOING
        Accounts = _context.Accounts.ToList();

        return Page();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the OnGetAsync() is underlined with red color and right click says: "not all code paths return a value. I've tried putting each directs inside and outside the brackets. Each one works alone, but I can't get an either or working. Thanks for the link but nothing there helped me.

Comment: @JustJohn I assumed you had more code than at `//KEEP GOING`. Either way, that as well needs to end with a `return` statement, `return Page();`. Updated my answer.

Comment: @JustJohn I also noticed your comment, to use _a plain old OnGet()_, so I added one as well.

Comment: Ha! Both worked! thank you very much. Just a simple return Page(). This is going to stay with me the rest of my career. Thank you.